# Cost of changing a value vs. accessing an array in C

Tags: c++, c, performance, optimization, processing-efficiency

This question was closed for being opinion based, so this is an edit to clarify what I meant by it.

Is there any way to make an educated guess regarding whether changing the value of a `double` will take more or less time than retrieving a `double` from an array? I understand that what is faster may be situational, the question is if there is any way to predict what is the faster method in a given situation. Alternatively if there is any "good practice" one should adhere to such that the compiler can do as much optimisation as possible.

This question is based on the knowledge that the time required to access a given piece of data depends on whether it is located in L1, L2, L3 (...) or RAM. Due to limited space in L1, L2, ... I would believe that it is marginally faster to repeatedly modify a single variable than to modify many different variables once. However, I have no idea how big the difference is, or if it is possible to predict/manipulate what data/instructions will be located in what cache/RAM.

Below is the question as it was originally stated:

The time an operation takes is (to my best knowledge) related to what memory cache the information you are using is stored. So i am wondering whether it may be more efficient to change the value of a double *2N* times rather than store *N* doubles in an array and then iterate over the array. The thought is that the variable being changed frequently will be stored in a lower level cache, so that it will be accessed marginally faster than the values stored in the array. The array is small enough that the entire array fits in RAM, the point is not to free up memory.

Example code of the two alternatives is shown below. Note that the computations here are simplified to better describe the essence of the question. In reality the arrays are two dimensional, and the computation of `tmp1` and `tmp2` are slightly larger, but is still only a simple dependency on the index:

```
#define DIM 1000
double states[DIM];
double time_derivatives[DIM];
double ambient_state = 3.0;
    
// Initialize states
for (int pos = 0; pos < DIM; pos++) {
    states[pos] = pos;
}

// Alternative 1
double tmp1;
double tmp2;

// Ends
tmp1 = 1;
tmp2 = 2;
time_derivatives[0] = (ambient_state - states[0]) * tmp1 + (states[1] - states[0]) * tmp2;
tmp1 = DIM;
tmp2 = DIM + 1;
time_derivatives[DIM - 1] = (ambient_state - states[DIM - 1]) * tmp2 + (states[DIM - 2] - states[DIM - 1]) * tmp1;

// Bulk
for (int pos = 1; pos < DIM - 1; pos++) {
    tmp1 = pos + 1;
    tmp2 = pos + 2;
    time_derivatives[pos] = (states[pos - 1] - states[pos]) * tmp1 + (states[pos + 1] - states[pos]) * tmp2;
}
    
// Alternative 2
double flows[DIM + 1];
double tmp1; //Some intermediate, neccesary calculation variable

// Flows at ends
tmp1 = 1;
flows[0] = (states[0] - ambient_state) * tmp1;
tmp1 = DIM;
flows[DIM] = (ambient_state - states[DIM - 1]) * tmp1;

// Flows in bulk
for (int pos = 1; pos < DIM; pos++) {
    tmp1 = pos + 1;
    flows[pos] = (states[pos] - states[pos - 1]) * tmp1;
}
// Compute time derivatives
for (int pos = 0; pos < DIM; pos++) {
    time_derivatives[pos] = flows[pos + 1] - flows[pos];
}
```

In alternative 1, a lot of calculations are "repeated" in the final for-loop as `(states[pos + 1] - states[pos]) * tmp1` in one iteration will equal  `- (states[pos - 1] - states[pos]) * tmp2` the next iteration. In alternative 2, all the differences are calculated and stored in the array `flows`, thereby reducing the total number of computations.

The question is essentially, what is the cost of a computational operation compared to the cost of storing and accessing a variable in an array? Are there limiting cases for when one will be more efficient than the other?

Comment: An optimizing compiler may reorder the code fairly significantly. If you want to know for certain, measure.

Comment: There are no guarantees. Profile both approaches and see what's faster.

Comment: The answer is here: https://quick-bench.com/

Comment: While some algorithms will be better than others, you haven't given any information that suggests either of your approaches is better than the other (e.g. less computational OR space complexity).   So it's virtually impossible to say without doing measurements.   And bear in mind that measurements will be specific to one compiler, set of optimisation settings, particular hardware configuration, etc

Comment: As always, the only way to know for sure is to measure.  Modern hardware is complex, and even if we think we know what's going on, it easy to be surprised.  My goal is to write clean, easy to understand, self documenting code.  That often times makes it easier for the compiler to do its optimizations and makes maintenance much easier. It's only after profiling and determining there is a problem that I try micro-optimize a section of code.

Comment: actually even benchmarking this in isolation can be misleading. The only way to be absolutely sure is to implement both for their real application and measure that

Comment: The only thing I would say is that modern Intel processors can detect and prefetch serial data (the 'Streaming' part in SSE), so accessing the memory sequentially should be preferable becuase there will be fewer stalls. Neither option appears to access memory this way.

Comment: With questions like this, I often find that the array variant is faster on expensive CPUs, because they have bigger L1+L2 caches, and the recalculation variant is faster on cheaper CPUs, because they have smaller L1+L2 caches.

Comment: Thank you for answers! I've edited a bit to clarify that the algorithms were meant as examples, while the essence of the question was related to memory access time as mentioned by @MooingDuck and @Skizz . 
If i could follow up @Skizz, do you mean that using a linked list and could give a benefit? In the second alternative the arrays ```pos```and ```flows``` are accessed by index in strictly increasing order, is this not "sequential enough"?

Comment: When one way isn't obviously faster: always default to the simplest one; the one where you are least likely to write a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true you can't know without measuring, but you run the risk of either measuring wrong, or not measuring some future computer.

Remember too that you could easily be measuring the wrong thing.  Programmer time is usually a lot more expensive than machine time.  Guessing — even guessing wrong — could be the best strategy, because it's quick.

So here's a basis for a quick guess.

About 20 years ago I worked on Monte-Carlo simulation system, something that requires lots of random numbers.  We spent weeks evaluating random number generators to pick one that introduced the least bias into our model.  Then we stored those numbers in an array, and used that array throughout our process.

About 10 years later we had cause to revisit that process, IIRC because we needed more numbers.  Along the way, we noticed that the array wasn't helping: it was quicker to call the RNG function each time we needed a number than to use the pre-generated array.  By a lot.

Random-number generation is a surprisingly complicated business with quite a bit of computation attached.  But it's a small algorithm, hardly a page of code.

The lesson I took away is that computation is cheap and cache memory is not.  I use that as a basis for my guesses all the time.  Feel free to do the same.

Comment: Thank you! I realise that my question came off as vague, but this was really what i was wondering about. Is it cheaper to repeatedly modify memory (many computations) or to access a lot of different memory adresses? 
I understand that you have to measure to be sure. But as i take it from you, an educated guess is that many computations (especially relatively simple computations) are cheaper than repeatedly accessing different values from an array.

Answer (score 0):

As several comments mentions, it's in general not possible to compare the performance of two alternative implementations (doing the same) solely by looking at the C code. First the modern compilers do all kind of "magic" to generate good performing code and when the code is executed, the processor does a lot of magic to execute the code as fast as possible. So you need to be an extreme expert in both your compiler and your processor to judge performance solely by looking at C code.

If your not an extreme expert (which very few are), **the only option is to measure how both perform in your real application.**

That said... It seems to me that your Alternative 2 is doing strange and unnecessary things. For instance:

```
// Flows in bulk
for (int pos = 1; pos < DIM; pos++) {
    tmp1 = pos + 1;
    flows[pos] = (states[pos] - states[pos - 1]) * tmp1;
}
// Compute time derivatives
for (int pos = 0; pos < DIM; pos++) {
    time_derivatives[pos] = flows[pos + 1] - flows[pos];
}
```

**Why have two loops?**

As far as I can see you can do with one loop, like:

```
for (int pos = 1; pos < DIM; pos++) {
    tmp1 = pos + 1;
    flows[pos] = (states[pos] - states[pos - 1]) * tmp1;
    time_derivatives[pos-1] = flows[pos] - flows[pos-1];
}
```

**Why have a flows-array?**

As far as I can see there is no reason for the `flows` array. Simply do:

```
tmp1 = 1;
flows_prev_loop = (states[0] - ambient_state) * tmp1;
for (int pos = 1; pos < DIM; pos++) {
    tmp1 = pos + 1;
    flows_this_loop = (states[pos] - states[pos - 1]) * tmp1;
    time_derivatives[pos-1] = flows_this_loop - flows_prev_loop;
    flows_prev_loop = flows_this_loop;
}
```

This way you have an **alternative 3** which avoids calculating the same several times **without** using an array.

I have a feeling that this alternative will beat both of yours... but to be sure, you need to **measure**

Comment: The OP does state "Note that the computations here are simplified" so the algorithm is not what the question is about, mainly memory access times. As others have said, profile the code to see which one works best.